# How many ways to ajax load page content in JQuery

Tags: jquery

All, I knew there is a method named [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which can load dynamic content from a page in JQuery. Is there any other ways to make it ? thanks!

Comment: @Cherniv It doesn't matter, both are fine. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually specified a link to the JQuery documentation. To the category 'Ajax' -> 'Shorthand functions' to be precise. If you go there, you see a total number of five shorthand functions:

- `get()`,
- `getJSON()`,
- `getScript()`,
- `post()` and
- `load()`.

All of these are a shorthand for specific uses of the single core function `JQuery.ajax()`, which you can also call directly.

So the answer is: 'there are six functions for Ajax, but actually it's just one'. :)

See: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: +1+1+1.... It is very appreciated to show me the way of How and Why ! awesome! I like your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  for asynchronous calls.

[These methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) perform the more common types of AJAX requests in less code.

- [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
- [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)
- [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)
- [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)